# What is hook1 in an ActiveX INF file?

Tags: activex

Currently I've seen hooks created for activeX installer archives in an INF file that use "hook1" and "hook" (to the left of the = sign). I'm confused about the differences in the two. Here is an example:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0
[Setup Hooks]
hook1=hook1

[hook1]
run=msiexec.exe /i "%EXTRACT_DIR%\ccScanning_msi.msi" /qn
```

Shouldn't it read "hook=hook1"? Is the "hook1" to the left simply a user-defined name with no real usefulness or meaning? How am I supposed to read and understand this syntax/structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you looked at the official documentation about this? it's available here: [Using Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741209%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have already read this. I think this quote from the documentation is of interest -- " Execution of hook1 is identical to the previous description of the hook as an unconditional hook." -- however, I'm not sure if it is answering my question. I don't really understand yet, and that documentation page doesn't seem to address my specific concern. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

In [Setup Hooks] section you can use any name because the meaning is "hook name"="section name"

So basically your inf file could look like this:

```
[Setup Hooks]
myFirstHook=myFirstHook
mySecondHook=mySecondHook

[myFirstHook]
...

[mySecondHook]
...
```

In section that describes a file

```
[mydll.dll]
Version=1,2,3,4
hook=myFirstHook
```

you have to use "hook" because its meaning is "key:hook"="section name".